# I want to write some data below each value on the XAxis in JFreeChart

Tags: java, spring, jfreechart, linechart

I want to add some data below the default XAxis numbering something like this. 
[image]

Mind my poor image editing..
I am using XYLineChart in JFreeChart so how can I achieve this..

Comment: Have looked at `SymbolAxis`? Multiple axes?

Comment: @trashgod Actually I don't want to replace the XAxis numbering but I want to add some more data below XAxis numbering as shown above. Apparently SymbolAxis is just replacing the default XAxis Numbering!! Which is not what I want!!

Comment: @trashgod I was able to get it working by using LineChart and DefaultCategoryDataset() for JFreeChart

Comment: Glad you got it working. You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). Adding a [mcve] will make the answer more useful to others.